# How to implement delegate and datasource methods for UICollectionView when it is inside a custom TableViewCell in iOS, objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

**Note : I don't want to use any third party libraries**

- I have `tableview` with with a custom `table view cell` (table view working fine).
- Now inside the `table view cell` I want to implement a `collection view`.
- Now my problem is , where should I implement the `delegate` methods and `data source` methods for the collection view, which is inside the `custom table view cell` . below is what I have tried.

**Tabel View Controller implementation**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FirstTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tvcell"];

    return cell;
}
```

**working properly**

now inside this `FirstTableViewCell` there is a `collection view`.

**This is my FirstTableViweCell.h File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic, nullable) IBOutlet UICollectionView *insideCollectionView;

@property (strong, nonnull,nonatomic) NSArray *mycollectionData;
- (void)setColletionData :(nonnull NSArray *)collectionData;

@end
```

**and this is my FirstTableViewCell.m File**

```
#import "FirstTableViewCell.h"

@implementation FirstTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.insideCollectionView.delegate = self;

    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setColletionData:(NSArray *)collectionData
{
    self.mycollectionData = collectionData;
    [self.insideCollectionView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *ccell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return ccell;
}

@end
```

**following method**

```
- (void)setColletionData:(NSArray *)collectionData
    {
        self.mycollectionData = collectionData;
        [self.insideCollectionView reloadData];
    }
```

I used to set the `array` for `collectionView`, in `cellforrowatindexpath` in `tableview`

> So what is the correct way to implement `DataSource` and `Delegate`
>   methods for the `CollectionView` which is inside the `Custom Table
>   View Cell`.

Comment: You are doing perfectly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Horraaaaaaaay ..... =D This is the completed answer for this.

**Table View Implementation .m file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FirstTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray *bbarray;
    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    bbarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"33",@"44", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FirstTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tvcell"];
    
    [cell setColletionData:bbarray];
    
    return cell;
}

@end
```

**Implementation inside the Custom Table View cell**

**custom table view .h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic, nullable) IBOutlet UICollectionView *insideCollectionView;

@property (strong, nonnull,nonatomic) NSArray *mycollectionData;
- (void)setColletionData :(nonnull NSArray *)collectionData;

@end
```

**custom table view .m file**

```
#import "FirstTableViewCell.h"

@implementation FirstTableViewCell


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // These two are very important.
    self.insideCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.insideCollectionView.dataSource = self;
   
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


//this method is used to set the data , call it in cell for row at index path in table view implementation.
    - (void)setColletionData:(NSArray *)collectionData
    {
        self.mycollectionData = collectionData;
        [self.insideCollectionView reloadData];
    }
    

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.mycollectionData.count);
    return [self.mycollectionData count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *ccell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return ccell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is essentially correct. The only real change you need is to update the collection view data source and delegate methods in the custom cell class so they properly reference `self.mycollectionData`.

For example. Change `numberOfItemsInSection` to:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.mycollectionData.count;
}
```

Comment: I did it  and checked with a break point. for `self.mycollectionData = collectionData;` it shows the count as `2`, but it didn't  call for any `UICollectionView` `delegate` methods inside my `custom table view cell`.
should I call `self.insideCollectionView.datasource = self;` inside the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: yep, I have to call self.insideCollectionView.datasource = self; in awake from nib method. now it works fine. thanks in advanced and I upvoted you.