# Uitableview with UICollectionviewcell and UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

i need to create below design

[image]

I am following this code to draw simple collection view with horizontal scroll inside a UITableView

Current sample code work like this

UITableView-> UICollectionViewCell as cell with horizontal scroll

What i want

i want : First row with UICollectionview with horizontal scroll and
Then rest row with Normal UITableviewCell to show data

How can i do it .

Comment: Use a `UIViewController`, at the top of the viewControllers view, add `UICollectionView` as subview. Add the `UITableView` as subview below the collectionView.

Comment: means-> UIViewcontroller->uitableview->uicollectionview ?

Comment: but i need all in a single tableview to be scrollable not a hack

Answer (score 2):

1. add  a `UITableView` to your `view controller` and implement it's `delegate` and `datasource` methods .(You can use `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`).
2. for the `fist cell` of the `first section` in your `tableview`, you should use a `custom tableview cell`.
3. Inside this custom `tableview cell`, you have to add your `collection view` with `horizontal scroll`, and implement its `delegate` and `data source` methods inside your `custom tableview cell class`.

these are the steps you have to do.

refer this [implement uicollectionview inside uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463099/how-to-implement-delegate-and-datasource-methods-for-uicollectionview-when-it-is) question for more.

Hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 1):

You should design a UITableViewCell which has a UICollectionView inside, and set this cell for the cell in section A and for Section B, you should design a new UITableview cell.

Comment: condition to be handle inside tableview?\

Comment: In UITableView  delegate : cell for row at index path, check if the index.section is 0 or 1, if it is 0 , load the tableviewcell for sectionA else load tableviewcell for section 1

Answer (score 1):

When tableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath call you can check for First section and when first section load you can create new UICollection view object load in first cell. Than next section will load you can work as normal tableview work.

Not- you need to implement UICollectionview delegate and datasource methods also.

Comment: I would rather go for the " 2 custom cells " route (stated by Anuradh & Saravana), which is much cleaner than putting everything in the `cellForRow`

Comment: that would be the other way to handle that condition.