# How can I use UICollectionViewCells in the UITableViewcells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

where one of my TableViewCell must have the CollectionView and other are custom TableViewcells which have different number of Labels and ImageViews.Here is the code from my ViewController:

```
func tableView(_tableView:UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)->Int{
    return seachable.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if seachable[indexPath.row].first.name != nil{
        let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! FristTableViewCell
        cell.firstOne.text = seachable[indexPath.row].first.name
        return cell
    }
    .........and so on
    else {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell4",for: indexPath) as! FourTableViewCell
        cell.collectioinView1.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
```

below is the code from TableViewCell with CollectionView:

```
extension FourTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! OneCollectionViewCell
        cell.collectionCellLabel.text = "a"
        return cell
    }
}
```

The error I have is :The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:

Comment: What is displayed after `because: `? It is very important.

Comment: I want to use the cells of tableview similar to that being used in the weather app in the IOS decives, where only one tableviewcell is having the Horizontal scroll.

Comment: You can design `Custom TableViewCell`  using `XIB` files easily . And then add `CollectionView` on `XIB` .

Comment: Yes i have added but i'm having the error as mentioned above.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463099/how-to-implement-delegate-and-datasource-methods-for-uicollectionview-when-it-is. it will help you. answer is in objective-C, but the concept is same